# Make cell editable using inlinenav

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid, cell

When using inlinenav i have a cell on want editable when Adding and not editable when being edited.  I used the onselectrow to set the cell editable properties to true or false depending on whether the user is editing or adding.  My issue is that this works well until the user clicks the cancel button.

if i click a row to edit the row shows as expected. the user then clicks cancel. if the next user action is to add a new row the row shows up but the cell does not change to editable.  I put alerts in and can see the property has changed to editable but it displays as non editable. it feels like the row is being generated before the onselectrow has time to set the property.  I saw an example using form editing where the editrow function was called, but i am not understanding if thats what i need to do, how to implement it, since it seems to mean once you select a row you go into edit mode and that is not what i want to happen until the edit icon is clicked.

Comment: you should show your code to make the problem more understandable or poitn you in the right direction

Comment: onSelectRow: function(id){
              if (id && id.contains('jqg')) {
                    var cm = grid_d.jqGrid('getColProp','p_week');
                    $('#roster_stats_d').jqGrid('setColProp', 'p_week', { editable: true });
                    last_stat = id;
              }
              else{
                $('#roster_stats_d').jqGrid('setColProp', 'p_week', { editable: false });
              }
 }

Comment: I am new to this so it wasnt clear to me how to tell when add/edit were being triggered.  I did notice the add created a unique id starting with jqg so i used that to tell it was an add. its a simple if/else setting the colprop.